# How do you indicate changes (deletions specifically) in a manuscript without using tracked changes or strikethrough?

Tags: publications, formatting

I have a manuscript accepted with minor changes. I had to delete and rewrite some texts as the reviewers suggested. The journal specifically asked "Please highlight the changes to your manuscript within the document by using bold or coloured or highlighted text. Please do not use track changes or strikethrough text". But I can't seem to figure out how to indicate deletion without using strikethrough. Any thoughts on how to do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Suggestion: after deleting a word, highlight from the last letter of the previous word, to the first letter of the latter word. This should create a highlight of three characters (last letter->space->first letter) indicating where something was deleted.

Comment: Ask whoever instructed you. The journal is a much better point of contact than we are!

Comment: Style issues are going to be different from one journal to the next, even from one editor to the next. Seek advice from the journal, then keep that advice in your "toolkit" for future submissions. Maybe the journal even has an on-line style guide for such things.

Answer (score 4):

There are times when one might just decide to ignore the rules. In your case, it sounds entirely reasonable to re-submit the document in two version: One that shows track changes including additions and deletions (struck through, if that's what your software does, or additions in blue and deletions in red), and one version that is the clean final product.

If they really really want to insist on their own rules, then you can still provide what they want. But in the end, you are satisfying the spirit of the request: To make it easy for anyone to see what you have changed. I'd give it a 95% chance that you can get away with that. In fact, I'd give it an about equally high chance that nobody who will handle your re-submission actually knows the rules well enough to know that they *could*, if they wanted to, call you out on the rules violation.

Answer (score 2):

What you are returning is a new draft, not the final copy. Another version will eventually be required. Simply provide a key either within the document or as a separate note stating that words in a given color have been (are to be) deleted. Bolding is a bit less useful since it can have other interpretations.

Put (or mark) the key itself in the color you will use, indicating that it, too, will be removed eventually.

Alternatively, ask for more specific instructions from the editor.